# Only use firebase for fcm

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

Is it possible to remove all analytics capabilities from firebase in my android app? I've found it's analytics capabilities to be really low as compared to just about any other solution.

Comment: See [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics).

Comment: @MichaelBleigh Thanks for this, but does this also remove the classes when using proguard?